# How can I pass a struct with strings from C++ to C#

Tags: c#, c++, dll

I have the following C++ code

```
#ifdef EXPORT_DLL
#define CfgAPI __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define CfgAPI
#endif


    struct WrkPaths
    {
    public:
        char *WrkDir;
        char *URL1;
        char *URL2;
        char *URL3;
    };

    CfgAPI int getURLFromDir(WrkPaths * pathCfg){

        pathCfg->WrkDir  = (char*)malloc( 5 * sizeof(char) );
        strcpy( pathCfg->WrkDir , "Test");
        return 0;
    }
```

The corresponding C# code

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

// namespace declaration 
namespace HelloWorldApp {

    // Class declaration 
    class Geeks {

        [StructLayout (LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        public struct WrkPaths {

            [MarshalAs (UnmanagedType.LPStr, SizeConst = 255)]
            public string WrkDir;
            [MarshalAs (UnmanagedType.LPStr, SizeConst = 255)]
            public string URL1;
            [MarshalAs (UnmanagedType.LPStr, SizeConst = 255)]
            public string URL2;
            [MarshalAs (UnmanagedType.LPStr, SizeConst = 255)]
            public string URL3;
        }

        [DllImport ("CfgAPI.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern int getRepoURLFromDir (
            ref WrkPaths wPath
        );

        // Main Method 
        static void Main (string[] args) {

            // statement 
            // printing Hello World! 
            Console.WriteLine ("Hello World!");

            WrkPaths wPath         = new WrkPaths();        
            int a = getRepoURLFromDir(ref wPath);

            Console.WriteLine (wPath.WrkDir.ToString ());


            // To prevents the screen from  
            // running and closing quickly 

            Console.ReadKey ();

        }
    }
}
```

On the screen only `Hello world` appears. How can I transfer data from C/C++ DLL to C#?

Comment: IIRC, Native C++ only had the char array. But .NEt String has a "FromCharArray" function. So you propably just send char arrays.

Comment: There is a nasty memory management problem with the strings, the pinvoke marshaller cannot call free() to release the storage.  The struct members would have to be IntPtr (Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi() to convert) and the argument must be [Out] ref WrkPaths.  Focus on the storage problem.